# update table - SQL replace function

Tags: sql

Can someone enlighten me on the REPLACE function when updating a table.

> UPDATE table SET field1 = replace(field1, '', '' );

How do you correct these bellow with sql function replace:

```
S.SHOW   into SHOW  
-NOW     into NOW   
TO BEGIN into BEGIN
TEA.FORTWO into TEA FORTWO
UL.SER.MASS into UL SERTIG MAS
st.mystreet into street mystreet
st mystreet into street mystreet
st.of.philadelphia into streets of philadelphia
```

Also, does anybody know a place where this is explained in some detail?

edit : refrased the question omitting the 'wildcards'.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? What is the logic involved ? More details please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use wildcard in replace() function, see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx). Syntax:

```
REPLACE ( string_expression , string_pattern , string_replacement )
```

The 2nd parameter is just a string and does not support wildcard such as % or _.

Comment: I have found some explanation here also :http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/replace.php

Answer (score 0):

REPLACE() does not have any support for wildcards, patterns, regular expressions, etc. REPLACE() only replaces one constant string for another constant string.

You have to try something complex for this